# Restangular: Insert an element from one collection to another collection with different route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

Ok, I have this collection that I get from 'users' endpoint and another collection, with the same structure, that comes from the owners/:id/users endpoint.

```
//Populates the collection
var collection1 = RestAngular.all('users').getList();
var collection2 = RestAngular.one('owners', id).all(users).getList();
```

so, collection1 points to the endpoint 'myDomain.com/users' and collection2 points to the endpoint 'myDomain.com/owners/1/users'

With the values of collection1 I populate a select, choose an option and then submit the form.

So, I need to take the element selected in the collection1 list, push to the collection2 and then save that freshly added element(not the whole collection, just the element).

```
collection2.push(collection1[0])
```

The problem is that the element pushed in collection2 from collection1 remembers it's route and its being pushed to 'myDomain.com/users'.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to push an clean object instead of restangularized collection element.

```
collection2.push(collection1.$object[0].plain())
```